# How does one dynamically take values from a Group, add it to an Array, and then print individual values in the Page Footer?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-2011

I have a report file, where the report provides information on a "Job" - so this is a "Job Ticket" report. Inside the Job Ticket, there is a group with details that provides information on individual "Components" of which there can be anywhere from 1 Component to 6 Components in any given Job. There is a field applied to each component which is a string and is the "ComponentType" ({sp_JobTicket.ComponentType}).

What I would like to do is put the value of each row of ComponentType into an Array, which I can then call in the Page Footer (i.e., so I can create a Text Object and in it call a value using something like "TypeforComponent[3]"), so even though every printed page will only show the full details of one component, the page footer for each page will provide an at-a-glance view of all the components and their types.

As it is right now, we just hand write the component types for all components on the printed page itself, but we can access the ComponentType through the database, so it seems like we should be able to get it to print on the report.

[image: ComponentType List Printed in the Page Footer]

Here is a full page preview of of a printed Job Ticket report that has 4 components (so in the Page Footer only 1-4 would have a value, 5-6 are empty), and where everything is currently laid out, and where we're hoping to get things placed:
[image: Full Report Preview]

Comment: ok got your idea..that is possible.. where are you struck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the simpler and more straight-forward solution to my problem was to not use an Array, but to create a Subreport.

[image: Subreport]

I accomplished this by creating a new report, linked it to the stored procedure used by my Job Ticket (main) report, and imported the data fields I needed. I then proceeded to change the Page Size for the subreport to fit into the size on the page (1.5" x 1"), set the Details section to "Format with Multiple Columns" in the section expert which made available a new "Layout Tab" which I entered and selected "Format Groups with multiple column[s]." Then I saved that as a separate file and imported that report into my main report as a Subreport. Finally I set the Subreport Links to link to my "JobNumber" field which my main ticket uses as a parameter and that Field to the parameter.

[image: Setting Subreport Links]

Completed Successfully:
[image: Completed Successful Report]

Answer (score 1):

Lots of questions but assuming this report is run for only 1 job ticket at a time here is one possibility:
Create formula called CT_Array and place in header1 section and suppress:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
stringvar array CT_Array ;
stringvar output := "";
numbervar i := ubound(CT_Array)+1;
redim preserve CT_Array[i];
CT_Array[i] := {sp_JobTicket.ComponentType};
```

Then create 6 formulas (CT_Var1 through CT_Var6) to read as follows:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
stringvar array CT_Array ;
CT_Array[1]
```

Replacing CT_Array[1] with the next array element number

Place those formulas where needed in page footer.

CT_Var2

```
WhileReadingRecords; stringvar array CT_Array ; 
if ubound(CT_Array) >
1 then CT_Array[2] else ""
```

etc... for CT_Var3 through 6

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering! Something seems not quite right as only the first var (CT_Var1) works. Subsequent ones cause an error: "A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array." When I un-suppress the GH1 section with the CT_Array formula in it, it shows in the preview that there is only 1 value for a "ticket" that should have 4 values (as there are 4 components).

Reminder: Report is grouped by sp_JobTicket.ComponentNumber, but the actual value needed is sp_JobTicket.ComponentType.

Comment: I edited answer ... sorry about that. I forgot that the size of the array needed to be evaluated

Comment: thanks for the update. That's stopped the errors from popping up, however it seems that subsequent vars only want to pull information from the first component ("SM"). Where on this one ticket, the expected component type values are: 1:SM, 2:QM, 3:QM, 4:Note, even with updating CT_Var2-4 they all show the value "SM".

Comment: Thanks for the reply CoSpingsGuy. As your solution didn't seem to want to work completely, I continued to investigate options and I ended up figuring out Subreports, and so used a Subreport to accomplish what I needed.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. I fully intended to get back here and help you but I somehow landed a reporting job yesterday so have been busy with that.